# SQL Server convert hexadecimal varchar value to INT

Tags: sql-server

I created a T-SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDecimalFromHexa (@HexValue VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   IF (CHARINDEX('0x',@HexValue) = 0)
      SET @HexValue = '0x' + @HexValue
   RETURN CONVERT(INT, @HexValue )    
END
```

Then I call my function like that

```
SELECT dbo.GetDecimalFromHexa ('0000385A')
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0x0000385A' to data type int.

Please correct me.

[Edit]
I want to get int output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDecimalFromHexa] (@HexValue VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   IF (CHARINDEX('0x',@HexValue) = 0)
      SET @HexValue = CONCAT ('0x', @HexValue)
   RETURN CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(varbinary, @HexValue, 1))    
END
GO
```

Comment: copypaste to update your existing function. watch for db in use (to be sure add: "USE [yourDBname] {new line} GO" before the alter

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), '0000385A', 2) AS INT)
```

Or try this -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDecimalFromHexa 
(
    @HexValue VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

   RETURN CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @HexValue, 2) AS INT)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle,

just execute `to_number` function.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('AB','xx') FROM dual
```

That's it. It will returns 171 number.